# How to replace bunch of tags with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I have a "aside" tag in this tag I have "div" which holds something like a side menu. I would like this menu to display only when user is logged in. If he is not I would like to have there instead of menu a login form. I know how I can check by JavaScript if php session was made, but I don't know how to replace all the code by other bunch of code. Here is a code:

```
<aside id="main_section_right">
    <div id="side_menu_div">
        <ul id="account_menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Now if user is not logged in I would like code inside "ul" tags to change to this.

```
<form>
    <li><input type="text" class="form" id="username" name="usr"/></li>
    <li><input type="text" class="form" id="password" name="paw"/></li>
    <li>
        <button type="submit" class="login_button" id="login_button">
            <b>Login</b>
        </button>
    </li>
</form>
```

Is there any way to do it with jQuery or JavaScript? So it's all together going to look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (logged_in) {
        document.getElementById("side_menu_div").innerHTML = 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("side_menu_div").innerHTML =
    }
</script>
```

But this work only if I'm changing text, not replacing tags. Well thank you for any help.

Comment: There's no reason for `innerHTML` to not work, after all, you're supposed to feed it `HTML`. Just make sure you're escaping the line breaks correctly.

Comment: Handle this server side when you build the page, don't use JS for it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still making no progress. Any chance you can show me at least a small piece of code, just to show me what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I'd do this server-side too. Unless you have ajax login, server-side would be a better approach.

Comment: You've tagged this question with "PHP"... just do it **server-side** with PHP, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea may be to combine the two elements within `#side_menu_div` and toggle their visibility dependent on the login status. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/jXYb6/)

```
<div id="side_menu_div">
  <div id="loggedin">
   <ul id="account_menu">
     <li class="current"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Edit Account</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="notloggedid" class="chklogin">
   <form>
    <ul>
     <li><input type="text" class="form" id="username" name="usr"/></li>
     <li><input type="text" class="form" id="password" name="paw"/></li>
     <li><button type="submit" class="login_button" id="login_button">
                     <b>Login</b></button></li>
     </ul>  
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

function to switch display:

```
function _setMenu(loginstatus){
 if (loginstatus){
    $('#loggedin').show();
    $('#notloggedin').hide();
 } else {
    $('#loggedin').hide();
    $('#notloggedin').show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could have the menu in a file, say *menu.html*, and the form in other file *form.html*.

```
var isLogged; // This variable shoud be a boolean indicating if the user is logged

if (isLogged) $("#main_section_right").load("menu.html");
else          $("#main_section_right").load("form.html");
```

By the way, you could do the same with the **UL** elment instead of the entire **aside** element, but changing the aside is better, because if not your ids (for example *#side_menu_div*) would not be a pretty good reference.